# How to TextInput component "clear" button

Tags: react-native

I'm using `react-native-testing-library` on a `react-native-elements` `Input` component. The component shows the clear button while editing.

How can I tap the clear button to test the side effects?

This doesn't work:

```js
const addressField = component.getByPlaceholder("Address");
addressField.clear();

// TypeError: addressField.clear is not a function
```

Comment: Try using .onClear() see whether it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `clear option`.

```js
handleSearchClear = () => {
this.setState({ query: "" })
}
....
<Input

  placeholder='BASIC INPUT'
  onClear={this.handleSearchClear}
  value={this.state.query}
/>
```

OR You can use `ref`

```js
this.input.clear();
...
<Input

  placeholder='BASIC INPUT'
  ref={ref => {this.input = ref;}}
  value={this.state.query}
/>
```